# Do we need a moldvay-dnd tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

As of this writing, [we have 7 questions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/search-new?tab=newest&q=moldvay%20is%3aquestion) explicitly asking for solutions within the Moldvay edition of D&D.

In chronological order, newest first:

- [Moldvay D&D First Round in Encounter](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/19987/moldvay-dd-first-round-in-encounter)
- [Melee Combat in Moldvay's D&D Basic](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/19924/melee-combat-in-moldvays-dd-basic)
- [How many things can a player do on his or her round?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/19185/how-many-things-can-a-player-do-on-his-or-her-round)
- [Turns vs. Rounds playing time in Moldvay D&D 1981 Ed](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/19164/turns-vs-rounds-playing-time-in-moldvay-dd-1981-ed)
- [Moldvay Basic D&D - Mapping using Charater Movement Rates](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/19156/moldvay-basic-dd-mapping-using-charater-movement-rates)
- [How can players learn the nature of magic items?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/13830/how-can-players-learn-the-nature-of-magic-items)
- [In early D&D, why would chainmail ever be preferred over plate armor?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5919/in-early-dd-why-would-chainmail-ever-be-preferred-over-plate-armor)

In light of the fact we have no tag for Moldvay's D&D, a few of these questions are just leaving the system in their title.

Generally we have a tag to distinguish between systems, and seven questions is probably enough to have a tag for Moldvay D&D. However I am concerned it may be counter-productive to have one. Is it worth distinguishing between Moldvay D&D and other AD&D systems tag-wise? Should we have a [moldvay-dnd](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moldvay-dnd) tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, we do, though it's a bit confusing.  Our tag  hierarchy for D&D is:

- `[dungeons-and-dragons]`

  - `[odnd]` - Holmes LBB
  - `[bx-dnd]` - Moldvay Basic and Cook Expert
  - `[dnd-becmi]` - Mentzer Red Box + (expert, companion, master, immortal)
  - `[adnd]` - aka 1e
  - `[adnd-2e]`
  - `[dnd-3e]`
  - `[dnd-3.5e]`
  - `[dnd-4e]` - includes Essentials
  - `[dnd-next]`
  - `[pathfinder]`

Plus some cruft that needs merging (dnd-5e, dnd-next-playtest, et al). Not sure why it's bx-dnd and not dnd-bx, it'd probably be easier to find the other way, and a tag synonym for dnd-mentzer to dnd-becmi would be fine. Also I'm not sure what dnd-basic is supposed to be - encompass the first 3 on that list?

Comment: Tag synonymized bx-dnd and dnd-moldvay to dnd-bx. Added a tag wiki for dnd-bx.

Comment: Seems like OD&D _is_ D&D Basic, or _The Basic Set_. See [this answer](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/2101/1204) and [this wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dungeons_%26_Dragons_Basic_Set) - there is no other "D&D basic" other than the first blue-box D&D.

Comment: Look harder.  All three of those games are referred to as "Basic" D&D. The dnd-basic tag has been applied to all of those variations so far on the site.

Comment: Ah, so D&D Basic is just as opposed to AD&D I guess. Whoops :(

Comment: I'm just not sure if there's value in a dnd-basic tag that encompasses all three. We have dungeons-and-dragons for everything, and there's no similar "all the advanced variants" tag because they're different enough that's not helpful.

Comment: We also have `[osr]` which is being used to tag "all pre-3.0 editions" but that seems painful.  Also a bunch tagged both bx and basic though just about bx; I'm removing basic from those.

Comment: Merged all dnd-basic to dnd-bx. Merged all dnd-next-playtest and dnd-5e to dnd-next. Synonyms set up.

Comment: I'm not too fussed either way, but the reason it was [bx-dnd] instead of [dnd-bx] is due to the network guidance to use the abbreviations that existing communities already use. It's generally called "B/X D&D" or just "B/X" sometimes leaving out the slash. "D&D BX" isn't attested anywhere. It also wasn't considered necessary to make it fit the general pattern of [dnd-whatever] because the tag search algorithm finds what you typed anywhere in the tag, not just at the beginning, so [bx-dnd] is equally discoverable to [dnd-bx]. It's *not* caught by favouriting/ignoring the [dnd-*] tag, though.

Comment: Sure, but as a result no one was using it (including you) on appropriate questions. Something needed changing.