# Where goes the [traveller]?

Tags: discussion, tags

A long time ago in a country far away (from me) a system was born. It was named [traveller](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/traveller).

Since then several others have taken up the work and created different yet similar systems based upon it. Some of those found a tag of their own ([mongoose-traveller](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mongoose-traveller), [mongoose-traveller-2](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mongoose-traveller-2), [traveller-5](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/traveller-5)) and others have not (see the traveller tag wiki).

Now, when new questions arise, how should they be handled? Should they have only the [traveller](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/traveller) tag and specify their system in the question itself? What about when the asker is not aware that there are multiple ones?

Should they have the [traveller](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/traveller) to honer their linage and their specific tag along with it?

Or should they just abandon their ancestry and use only the most specific tag.

Comment: Similar discussions about other tags: [How Should We Tag D&D Versions?](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/2760) • [Clean up tagging for "World of Darkness" related questions](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/4933)

Comment: I don't know if it adds anything useful to the context, but I only made that edit to [tag:traveller]'s tag wiki a day or two ago. (Prompted to do so by this week's questions mostly about Mongoose, but tagged [tag:traveller].) So my assertion in the wiki that it refers to all-editions-or-none is not well-vetted and may need updating!

Comment: @nitsua60 Oh-ho! That's good to know. It's a fair description of how the tag *had been* getting used for years though, so it counts as perceptive and helpful. :) (Even if, as might be the case, the wider community's assumptions are changing and our tagging may need to sharply change to suit.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- There is some precedent in reserving the "basic" tag for a set of editions for only questions that are about *all* or *many* editions. That precedent was set by our discussions about [how to tag D&D questions](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2760) though, and D&D being the 800 lb gorilla of RPGs, it is somewhat exceptional.

  The advantage of avoiding the extra tag is so that more room is available for other tags that might be needed for the question. D&D being a widely-known set of game editions makes this feasible because most questions start with the understanding that they *have* to be about a specific edition, not just the non-specific “D&D”.
- There's also precedent for tagging questions about smaller games / games that generate fewer questions with both a general tag and the game-specific tag (see [Clean up tagging for "World of Darkness" related questions](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4933)).

  The advantage of this approach is that all the questions about a particular game's editions can be found easily under the general tag. This can be useful when editions are very similar and have points of compatibility, or when people interested in one edition are often interested in many or all editions (which happens more often when editions are very similar).

I *think* Traveller questions here fall into the second category: nearly always specifically about one game, but people who play one edition of Traveller seem to be interested in many other editions, as sources of ideas and rules to borrow. If that's the case, then I think we should tag with both [traveller](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/traveller) and the [game-specific-tag] when available, so that they can all be found under the [traveller](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/traveller) tag. In that case, *just* the [traveller](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/traveller) tag would mean either Classic or one of the other “old” editions, which we would have to see clearly indicated in the question.

However, that's now. If we see an influx of many Traveller questions — which we might, if the recent releases of Traveller 5 and Mongoose Traveller 2 instigate a renaissance in interest in the games — then we may want to avoid the “tag tax” of needing to include the general tag, as with our D&D tags. That would also free up the general [traveller](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/traveller) tag to mean something more specific, such as “questions relevant to most/all Traveller editions” or perhaps specifically GDW's 1977 *Traveller* (though in either case, we would need to make a new tag to represent the other one).

(A good heuristic for whether we might need to make that choice is if we get a lot of questions tagged [traveller](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/traveller) that don't bother saying what game they mean and turn out to *not* be Classic. That would indicate that how to choose among our Traveller tags is not obvious and that we need more specific, obvious tag names to help guide new askers.

This is actually how [mongoose-traveller](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mongoose-traveller), [mongoose-traveller-2](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mongoose-traveller-2), and [traveller-5](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/traveller-5) came about: I noticed a small influx of questions that just assumed that readers would see “Traveller” and equate it with “current” Traveller (despite there being two-maybe-three). I knew we needed those three tags for fans of the recent Traveller games to pick, so they won't assume that saying “Traveller” means “obviously the current edition”.)

**TL;DR**: I think we should use both [traveller](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/traveller) and [game-specific-tag] where available, unless we see a sharp rise in the number of questions about Traveller games.